# C++ Odd behaviour with vector populated with constructor

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error, stdvector

I'm experiencing some "odd behaviour" with populating a vector value with the use of the constructor.

So, I have this block class that populates this static vector called blockList whenever the constructor is called.

```
static std::vector<Block*> blockList;

Block::Block(float x, float y)
    : RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(WIDTH, HEIGHT)) {
    blockList.push_back(this);
    setFillColor(sf::Color(221, 221, 221, 255));
    setPosition(x, y);
}
```

Now, when I populate the values in another class I have called "Game" ; in its constructor like so:

```
Game::Game(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    // other code here

    Block firstBlock(10, 10);
    // possible more blocks here
}
```

and then attempt to draw, it crashed. In addition, the coordinates of this block print out to be (x: 9.8439e-12, y: 9.84394e-12). Now what I've tried doing is throwing it in the draw method (which I'm aware is bad as it's constantly being called but for debugging purposes):

```
void Game::drawObjects() {
    // draw other shapes here

    Block oneBlock(50.0f, 50.0f);

    std::cout << std::string(10, '-') << std::endl;
    for (Block* block : Block::getBlockList()) {
        std::cout << block->getPosition().x << " - " << block->getPosition().y << std::endl;
        window->draw(*block);
    }
    std::cout << std::string(10, '-') << std::endl;
}
```

The coordinates and the drawing of the object work perfectly (even if the vector is being populated heavily). So I'm wondering why this is happening and a possible way to work around this. I don't like the idea, but perhaps I should have flag to detect whether or not they've been created and then create them in the draw method?

Comment: Did you happen to read the compiler warnings? They're important.

Comment: Also, you don't show any mechanism which removes blocks in their destructor. Stop being clever, and just add a ::Add and ::Remove method.

Comment: @DavidLively No there aren't any warnings as it appears to be a logical error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So I'm wondering why this is happening

In `Game::Game()`, `Block firstBlock(10, 10);` means `firstBlock` is a local object which will be destroyed when get out of the scope of `Game::Game()`. Then the pointer saved by `blockList.push_back(this);` in `blockList` becomes dangled pointer, and access it leads to UB.

> and a possible way to work around this.

Do you really need a vector of *pointer* here? You could just

```
static std::vector<Block> blockList;
```

then use it like:

```
Block firstBlock(10, 10);
blockList.push_back(firstBlock);
```

Comment: Or they could use `std::shared_ptr<Block>`, which might be "better". I also suspect that `Block::~Block()` doesn't delete the pointer. Personally, I'd make the `blockList` a distinct class with explicit `add` and `remove` methods.

Comment: @KenY-N If pointer is necessary then smart pointers will be better. Anyway making a distince `blockList` is a good idea.

Comment: I put "better" in quotes as I felt "less worse" would have been more accurate but too blunt.

Answer (score 1):

As addendum to songyuanyao answer.

You should think a bit what is owned by what in your app.

I think `Game` can own all the blocks, so having `vector<Block> blocks;` inside Game is IMO OK.

Or if there's lot of stuff, and you want to keep `Game` a bit shorter, you may introduce some `World` wrapper class owning the blocks, then `Game` has among other things single `World world;` instance, which contains the `blocks` vector.

Avoid naked pointers in the source, they often just point out, that you are not sure who should own the instance of the object. Having everything "belonging somewhere" will make all the memory releasing just question of going out of scope. For example if your `main` has `Game game;` local instance, it will get completely destructed upon exiting `main` (releasing also the inner `world` instance with the vector of all `blocks`).

Then the C++ feels almost like having GC, but you don't need to be afraid with *when* the resource releasing happens, as you make that explicit by exiting the particular scope.